# what is advantage of create role dynamically in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, roles

I have a question that really confused me!
I've read [ASP.NET MVC 5 Identity: Implementing Group-Based Permissions Management Part I](http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/02/19/ASPNET-MVC-5-Identity-Implementing-Group-Based-Permissions-Management-Part-I.aspx) and this article [ASP.NET MVC 5 Identity: Implementing Group-Based Permissions Management Part II](http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/02/19/ASPNET-MVC-5-Identity-Implementing-Group-Based-Permissions-Management-Part-II.aspx) that describes how to create roles dynamically and assign each of them to groups and each user assign to groups.

but I must hard code Authorize attribute above of each Action yet! so, what is advantage of create roles dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends , you can create your own authorize filter and make everything configurable and no need to hard code any of the data. Now with the ASP.NET MVC 5 you can add the attribute and the Global level , and we have controller level and action level for from long time.You can google and get a lot of example of creating custom authorization see here for one of the example

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/G54G220114-Custom-Authentication-and-Authorization-in-ASP.NET-MVC.html